# Trying to find a more efficent way to filter files

Tags: java

Given a list of deviceIds, I am trying to come up with a more efficient way of handling duplicates. When a duplicate is found in the deviceId list, I need to keep only the latest file and delete the others. What i've come up with so far seems to work ok, but i'm wondering if it can be made more efficient? My current method doesn't seem to scale well, for example, it processes 25,000 files in 5 seconds but takes 70 seconds for 100,000 files. Any thoughts?

```
List<File> filteredList;
        for(int i = 0; i < deviceIds.size(); i++) {
            if(i < (deviceIds.size()-1) && deviceIds.get(i).equals(deviceIds.get(i+1))) {
                filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(fileList, new DeviceIdFilter(deviceIds.get(i))));
                Collections.sort(filteredList, new OldestFileComparator());
                for(int t = 0; t < (filteredList.size()-1); t++) {
                    filteredList.get(t).delete();
                }
            }
        }

private static class DeviceIdFilter implements Predicate<File> {
    private String deviceId;
    private DeviceIdFilter(final String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final File file) {
        return file.getName().contains(deviceId);
    }
}

public class OldestFileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    public int compare(File filea, File fileb) {
        if (filea.lastModified() > fileb.lastModified()) {
            return +1;
        } else if (filea.lastModified() < fileb.lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I implemented TacticalCoders solution which worked wonderfully, processing 100,000 files in 0.60 seconds.

```
    Map<String, List<File>> fileMap = new HashMap<String,List<File>>();
    String deviceId;
    List<File> deviceFileList;
    for(File file : fileList) {
        deviceId = getDeviceId(file.getName());
        if(fileMap.containsKey(deviceId)) {
            fileMap.get(deviceId).add(file);
        } else {
            deviceFileList = new LinkedList<File>();
            deviceFileList.add(file);
            fileMap.put(deviceId, deviceFileList);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> mapEntry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
        deviceFileList = mapEntry.getValue();
        if(deviceFileList.size() > 1) {
            Collections.sort(deviceFileList, new OldestFileComparator());
            for(int t = 0; t < (deviceFileList.size()-1); t++) {
                deviceFileList.get(t).delete();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can look at a method that divides your list into smaller ones (like 25,000) does your sort method, then merges them together with a mergesort kind of algorithm

Comment: A simpler comparator would return `filea.lastModified().compareTo(fileb.lastModified())`.  Not faster, just a little cleaner.  But beware nulls (also a problem in your implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current method doesn't seem to scale well, for example, it
>   processes 25,000 files in 5 seconds but takes 70 seconds for 100,000
>   files. Any thoughts?

That's because you have an *O(n^2)* algorithm (it can potentially degenerate to much worse than *O(n^2)* if you happen to have mostly duplicates, in which case you'd be doing an *O(n log n)* sort in addition to your two for loops, but I take it you don't have 100 000 files being basically always the same duplicate).

If I read the problem correctly you could just do a first pass where you'd build a *Map<String,List<File>>* (where the key would the (sub)String corresponding to the device ID).

After that first pass every file that has a duplicate would be in a list with at least two entries while every file that has no duplicate would be in its own list.

You'd then iterate over your map and everytime you find a *List<File>* with more than one entry, then you sort that list according to the date and delete all but the latest file.

Would that work?

**EDIT** you have to be careful with your device IDs: I don't know at all what they look like but if one ID can be, say, "nop100" and another device ID can be, say, "nop1000", then if you process "nop100" before "nop1000" you may be in trouble with your *contains* method call (because "nop1000" would wrongly match the device ID of "nop100" devices).  As far as I can tell this issue exist in the partial code you posted too.  There are workarounds of course but it's hard to go further without knowing more about the kind of filenames you're processing.

Comment: TacticalCoder, thanks for the excellent solution. I implemented this and processing the same set of 100,000 files took only 0.60 seconds. As for the deviceIds, they are always a fixed length (16 characters), so the String contained seemed appropriate.

Comment: @Hoofamon: great :)   Oh OK, if the device IDs are always 16 characters long then you should not have any issue.